# How to use "pointrange" function with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, errorbar

Suppose I have the mock data below:

```
example <- structure(list(country = c("Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
                       "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Austria", "Austria", 
                       "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                       "Austria", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
                       "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"), date = c(1000, 1200, 
                                                                             1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 1400, 
                                                                             1500, 1600, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 
                                                                             1700, 1750, 1800), fit.0.025quant = c(0.828708096446602, 2.4420979507703, 
                                                                                                                   2.62414677055878, 2.63329989559212, 2.53354700323539, 1.65000976000248, 
                                                                                                                   0.752830563369601, 0.662779471528981, 0.633370287301323, 0.631451022500498, 
                                                                                                                   0.649758893615039, 0.650073875566409, 0.650081079761908, 0.650081254451237, 
                                                                                                                   0.650081079637564, 0.650073875566409, 0.649758893615039, 0.631451022500498, 
                                                                                                                   0.631451022500498, 0.649758893615039, 0.650073875566409, 0.650081079761908, 
                                                                                                                   0.650081254451237, 0.650081079637564, 0.650073875566409, 0.649758893615039, 
                                                                                                                   0.631451022500498), fit.mean = c(1.1903534469417, 2.83004352114819, 
                                                                                                                                                    2.9806558994056, 2.9875417232584, 2.90452442326781, 1.99995962905406, 
                                                                                                                                                    1.09518775382276, 1.01031925709265, 1.00141486550036, 0.999999948657743, 
                                                                                                                                                    0.999999976399706, 0.999999973245836, 0.999999973352837, 0.999999968778261, 
                                                                                                                                                    0.999999973272607, 0.999999973245836, 0.999999976399706, 0.999999948657743, 
                                                                                                                                                    0.999999948657743, 0.999999976399706, 0.999999973245836, 0.999999973352837, 
                                                                                                                                                    0.999999968778261, 0.999999973272607, 0.999999973245836, 0.999999976399706, 
                                                                                                                                                    0.999999948657743), fit.0.975quant = c(1.61387277731566, 3.17388806195699, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           3.32641599958393, 3.33420679881888, 3.24684592681982, 2.34991876603736, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           1.46568276539042, 1.36373981325973, 1.37069925216457, 1.36867909649403, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           1.35026553811603, 1.34998364436204, 1.34997767551695, 1.34997753475153, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           1.34997767544381, 1.34998364436204, 1.35026553811603, 1.36867909649403, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           1.36867909649403, 1.35026553811603, 1.34998364436204, 1.34997767551695, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           1.34997753475153, 1.34997767544381, 1.34998364436204, 1.35026553811603, 
                                                                                                                                                                                           1.36867909649403)), row.names = c(NA, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are three groups (*country*).

I want to use "*pointrange*" function for every *country*, so that for every *date*, the mean of a pointrange was equal to the corresponding *fit.mean*, upper point to the corresponding *"fit.0.975quant"*, lower point to *"fit.0.025quant"*

For now, I can only suggest chopping the data and then plotting each *country* separately, like this:

```
example.italy <- example[-c(10:27), ]
example.italy$date <- as.factor(example.italy$date)

figure <- ggplot(example.italy,
             aes(x = date, y = fit.mean)) + aes(y = fit.mean, group=1) + xlab("Time periods") + ylab("DV") + theme(legend.position = "none") + annotate("pointrange", x = "1000", y = example.italy[1,4], ymin = example.italy[1,3], ymax = example.italy[1,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1200", y = example.italy[2,4], ymin = example.italy[2,3], ymax = example.italy[2,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1300", y = example.italy[3,4], ymin = example.italy[3,3], ymax = example.italy[3,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1400", y = example.italy[4,4], ymin = example.italy[4,3], ymax = example.italy[4,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1500", y = example.italy[5,4], ymin = example.italy[5,3], ymax = example.italy[5,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1600", y = example.italy[6,4], ymin = example.italy[6,3], ymax = example.italy[6,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1700", y = example.italy[7,4], ymin = example.italy[7,3], ymax = example.italy[7,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1750", y = example.italy[8,4], ymin = example.italy[8,3], ymax = example.italy[8,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5) + annotate("pointrange", x = "1800", y = example.italy[9,4], ymin = example.italy[9,3], ymax = example.italy[9,5], 
       colour = "red", size = 1.5)
```

Which will produce:

[image]

But what if the data contains 15-20 groups (countries)? Then chopping the data and plotting each country separately would be inpracticable.

Any suggestions guys on how to plot pointranges across different facets in one go?

You can suggest other functions similar to *pointrange* (may be *errorbars*?). Basically, for every row in data, I want to show the range spanning from *"fit.0.025quant"* to *"fit.0.975quant"*, and *fit.mean* can be dropped.

Comment: Rustam. The least to share would be your plotting code. It looks as the only thing you need to add would be `+ facet_wrap(~groupvar)`, but it’s impossible to guess without _any_ code

Comment: and best would be to also share your data in a way that we can use it. E.g., you could post the output of `dput(your_dataframe)`,

Comment: @tjebo, thank you for suggesting dput(). I tried to provide data and some code. Let me know if the question still seems unclear.

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/). There shgould be an easy solution to this question, but you need to help yourself by making it easy for us to help you

Comment: @Limey, please have a look at the edits above. Are those correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read a bit into ggplot. Instead of using `annotate`, I suggest to use `geom_pointrange`, and then you can simply pass the columns as aesthetics into a single (!) call to that geom. Using facet_wrap then becomes really easy.

```r
ggplot(example, aes(x = date, y = fit.mean)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = fit.0.025quant, ymax = fit.0.975quant), color = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is the easy solution to which I referred.